# wpf mvvm ImageSelector

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm, move, resize-image

I have one project with mvvm. I load image with .jpg format by click load button in my project. I want to select part of this image and move it and re size it such as paint by click on rectangle tool in my menu but i don't know how

view code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="240*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <Image Source="{Binding MyImage.Source}" ></Image>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Width="70" Height="40" Command="{Binding LoadCommand}">Load Image</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

viewModel code:

```
 #region Property
    private Image _MyImage;
    public Image MyImage
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyImage;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyImage");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public ImageViewModel()
    {
        _MyImage = new Image();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    RelayCommand _LoadCommand;
    public ICommand LoadCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_LoadCommand == null)
            {
                _LoadCommand = new RelayCommand(param => LoadCommandExecute());
            }
            return _LoadCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void LoadCommandExecute()
    {

        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
            "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
            "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [Drag Selection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148503/Simple-Drag-Selection-in-WPF) is one way to go about this. After you have your drag selection implemented, check the position of the selection rectangle in relation to the image, crop out that portion of the image and allow it to modified whichever way you please.

If you have trouble along the way, post some code and we will try our best to solve it.